# Using foreign keys in ORMLite

Tags: android, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, ormlite

I have a class

```
   @DatabaseTable(tableName = "subjects")
public class Subject {
    private static final String SUBJECT_ID = "subject_id";
    @SerializedName("subject_id")
    @DatabaseField(columnName = SUBJECT_ID,id = true,generatedId = false)
    int id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
    String title;
    public Subject()
    {}
    public int getSubjectId() 
    {
         return this.id;
    } 
    public String getSubjectTitle() 
    {
         return this.title;
    }
    public void setSubjectId(int id)
    {
         this.id = id;
    }
    public void setSubjectTitle(String title)
    {
         this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {       
    return "{title="+title +" "+"subject_id"+id+"}";    
    }

}
```

which is in reference "many to one" with class:

```
    @DatabaseTable(tableName = "categories")
public class Category {
    public final static String CATEGORY_TITLE_FIELD_NAME = "title";
    public final static String SUBJECT_TITLE_FIELD_NAME = "subject";
    private static final String SUBJECT_ID = "subject_id";
    @SerializedName("id")
    @DatabaseField(id = true, generatedId = false)
    int id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING, columnName = CATEGORY_TITLE_FIELD_NAME)
    String title;
    @SerializedName("subject")
    @DatabaseField(columnName = SUBJECT_ID,foreign = true, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    Subject subject;


    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(int id, String title, Subject subject) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public int getCategoryId() {

        return this.id;
    }

    public String getCategoryTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public Subject getCategorySubject() {
        return this.subject;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setCategoryTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setCategorySubject(Subject subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{title=" + title + " " + "id=" + id + "subject" + subject+ "}";
    }

}
```

And I add subjects first at my Activity and then Categories. If I don't use references, everything works fine. When I want to make Subject object as foreign key, I get:

```
    08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049): java.sql.SQLException: Unknown field 'subject_id' from the Android sqlite cursor, not in:[title, id]
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseResults.findColumn(AndroidDatabaseResults.java:97)
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.resultToJava(FieldType.java:793)
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.BaseMappedQuery.mapRow(BaseMappedQuery.java:60)
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.getCurrent(SelectIterator.java:270)
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.nextThrow(SelectIterator.java:161)
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:161)
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.query(BaseDaoImpl.java:261)
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder.query(QueryBuilder.java:262)
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at com.assignmentexpert.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:276)
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at com.assignmentexpert.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-21 18:19:24.369: W/System.err(4049):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-21 18:19:24.419: I/ApplicationPackageManager(4049): cscCountry is not German : SEK
08-21 18:19:24.549: D/AndroidRuntime(4049): Shutting down VM
08-21 18:19:24.549: W/dalvikvm(4049): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.assignmentexpert/com.assignmentexpert.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at com.assignmentexpert.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:66)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
08-21 18:19:24.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You will hot me in the face, but do not use orm on android...

Comment: ORMLite really increase the speed of development in android, especially if you have been working with ormlite before, but perfomance is not comparable to standard android framework. When i switched from ormlite to poor android classes some querries become faster multiple times. Android framework has a lot of tasty things to decrease memory usage, like "windowing" etc. So in my opinion learning android framework is worth of time you will spend on it. This all is just my opinion. nothing more...

Answer (score 0):

Remove application and install it again with Subject and Category as above. As I understand this error may happened when you add columnName = SUBJECT_ID in Subject class at the middle of application development when DB have already created.